# Edit Publish Date in second language

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Some of you might know the issue with the publishing and expiring date of elements and pages in other languages than the default.

Setting the dates in the default language works perfectly. I copied the element into the secondary language. But there, the backend form fields (starttime / endtime) are disabled and therefore nothing will be en- or disabled at certain dates.

I already found something (basically a script to re-enable the BE form fields)

```
t3lib_div::loadTCA('tt_content');
unset($TCA['tt_content']['columns']['starttime']['l10n_display']);
unset($TCA['tt_content']['columns']['starttime']['l10n_mode']);
unset($TCA['tt_content']['columns']['endtime']['l10n_display']);
unset($TCA['tt_content']['columns']['endtime']['l10n_mode']);
```

This is quite old, so either this isn't working or I'm adding these lines to the wrong file since 'typo3conf/extTables.php' (the file they told me to put them) doesn't exist anymore.

*Edit:* because someone asked for it, here is my language setup TS

```
### language config
config {
    linkVars = L
    uniqueLinkVars = 1
    sys_language_uid = 0
    language = default
    locale_all = de_DE.utf8
}

# Setting up the language variable "L" to be passed along with links
#config.linkVars = L
#config.sys_language_mode=content_fallback
#config.sys_language_overlay=hideNonTranslated

[globalVar = GP:L=3]
config {
    linkVars = L
    uniqueLinkVars = 1
    sys_language_uid = 3
    language = en
    locale_all = gb_UK
    htmlTag_langKey = en
}
[global]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have different publishing dates for different languages, this configuration works in TYPO3 6.2:

```
// Enable starttime and endtime for non-default language
unset($GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['starttime']['l10n_display']);
unset($GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['starttime']['l10n_mode']);
unset($GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['endtime']['l10n_display']);
unset($GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['endtime']['l10n_mode']);
```

`t3lib_div::loadTCA('tt_content');` is no longer needed as of TYPO3 6.2 and you should use `$GLOBALS['TCA']` instead of `$TCA`.

Just put this in `typo3conf/extTables.php`.

If you don't have an extTables.php file yet, you can create a new PHP file and reference it in the DB part of LocalConfiguration:

```
'DB' => array(
    'extTablesDefinitionScript' => 'extTables.php',
    [...]
```

Comment: Yes, my answer only covers how to re-enable the fields as you asked. I guess biesior helps you finding the underlying problem that brought you to re-enabling these fields. But since in some cases it can be useful to have different values, I posted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Translated records inherits these fields from the *default* language so you do not need to set its values manually (their `l10n_mode` is [`exclude`](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Index.html#columns-properties-l10n-mode))

`l10n_display` is used just for preview, so you can check start and end times without opening record in default lang.

**Edit:** Uncomment the line `config.sys_language_mode=content_fallback`, otherwise it takes the non-default language "*as it is*" without checking parent's settings. you can also set fallback order if required see the description: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#setup-config-sys-language-mode

Finally if you want to display only translated elements also uncomment the `config.sys_language_overlay=hideNonTranslated` line.

Comment: Can't believe sorry ;) just tested these combinations on 6.2 worked like a charm - did you clear the cache ? Also use TypoScript Analyzer tool to make sure it isn't overwritten again somewhere _later_

Comment: Cache cleared, never overwritten. With uncommenting, the field of the secondary language inherits the "starttime" of the default one, but without effect at the FE (still displayed). Unsetting the stuff in the TCA inherits the values and makes the fields editable, which is nice ;)